# alter table 'xyztaable' auto_increment=201; not working in mysql. why?

Tags: mysql

Dear MySQL pros out there:  I wonder what I am doing wrong.  My code is like:

```
use testdb;
drop table testtable;
create table testtable (   
    ID int NOT NULL,
    lastn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    firstn varchar(20));
Select  * from testtable;
alter table testtable auto_increment = 7001;
insert into testtable (lastn,firstn) values('kim','jeff');
Select  * from testtable;
insert into testtable (lastn,firstn) values('Lee','jim');
Select  * from testtable;
```

The table generated as follows:   (no effect from "alter" statement)

```
# ID, lastn, firstn
'0', 'kim', 'jeff'
'0', 'Lee', 'jim'
```

Comment: When you create the table, you need to  set the `ID` field to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  Then when you alter the table, the seed should work.  As is, the `ID` field in just an `int`, which when set to `not null` can default to 0 in `Mysql`.

Comment: Why should you ever use ALTER ... AUTO_INCREMENT= ?  If you need to store kim as 7001, simply specify it when inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change your CREATE TABLE command to set the ID field to auto increment and initialise it like this:

```
create table testtable (   
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    lastn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    firstn varchar(20))
AUTO_INCREMENT = 7001;
```

or alter the table afterwards:

```
create table testtable (   
    ID int NOT NULL,
    lastn VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    firstn varchar(20));

ALTER TABLE testtable MODIFY COLUMN ID INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE testtable AUTO_INCREMENT = 7001;
```

Comment: Dear mhawke-thank you for your time & guide.  This will help a novice in mysql like me to be able to solve his nagging problem!!

Comment: @chanoh: you're welcome. If this answer correctly addresses your question consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: What is upvoting. mhawke?

Comment: up voting = Vote for this answer (press the up arrow at the top of this answer). You can also accept the answer as being the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

`ID` needs to be both AUTO_INCREMENT and the PRIMARY KEY.  (Those are "sufficient" but not completely "necessary".)